# Is forcing a user to update the app forbidden by Apple?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I recently added a popup to my app where I am forcing a user to update the app. I am showing a popup with a single "Update" button and when the user taps on it, I forward him to AppStore to update the app. So the user cannot skip the popup and cannot dismiss it. Only can go to AppStore and update to the latest version.

So my question is, is it okay to do so? Am I breaking any AppStore rule by doing so?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You cannot expect the backend of any app to support all versions of the app that were available for the last 10 years. That being said you should only force the user to update if it is really necessary, if you just add a new convenience feature for example there is no need to force everyone to update.

Answer (score 1):

No, a lot of apps do this, when they have patched critical bugs and want the user to update, otherwise they cannot use the app. I have seen that in games where they have patched hacks or in banking apps sometimes.